# Use Nhibernate to sort by a calculated property that's not mapped

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, projection

I have these classes:

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Tax { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal NetSalary { get { return Salary * (1 - Tax); } }
}


public class EmployeeMap : ClassMap<Employee>
{
    WithTable("Employees");
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Salary);
    Map(x => x.Tax);
}
```

And I'm retrieving the employees form the database like this:

```
var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Employee>();
criteria = criteria.AddOrder(Order.Asc(sortProperty)); // sortProperty is a string
```

Now this works well if I want to sort by `Salary`, but I would like to sort by `NetSalary`. How would I achieve that? I can't change the database. I found that there's an overload of `Order.Asc()` that takes in a projection. I'm sure that I have to create a projection in that criteria and feed it there, but I have found no info on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Although not the cleanest approach, you can define a projection for your calculated property, like so:

```
var netSalaryProjection = Projections.SqlProjection("Salary * (1 - Tax) as NetSalary", new[] { "NetSalary" }, new IType[] { NHibernateUtil.Decimal});
```

And use it for sorting:

```
criteria.AddOrder(Order.Asc(netSalaryProjection));
```

Note that this would likely work with SQL Server and possibly other providers.

Comment: Note that (at least on the NHibernate version I'm using) the `AS` clause in the SQL fragment is absolutely necessary, or else the entire string will be truncated to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing the calculated value? This will require moving the calculation logic to the setter and adding a column for storage. It will perform better when ordering the data on reads since the calculation is performed during write. This will also make the order by query simple. Hope this helps.